# Remove exclamation mark in variable in batch script

Tags: string, batch-file, replace

I have made a batch script that tests all valid Winrar archives on a drive. It works pretty well but I have run into trouble when the file or folder name contains an exclamation mark (!).

This is where I am thus far ("ECHO !test!" is for testing purposes):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* skip=2" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\WinRAR.exe" /V "Path" 2^>nul') DO SET sti=%%c
IF EXIST "%sti%\WinRAR.EXE" (
    SET PATH="!sti!";!PATH!
    SET count=0
    SET countall=0
    SET countpct=0
    IF EXIST archive_errors.log MOVE archive_errors.log archive_errors.log.bck
    FOR /R %%z IN (*.rar *.zip *.arj *.lzh *.ace *.7z *.gz *.uue *.bz2 *.jar *.xz *.z) DO SET /A countall+=1 >nul 2>&1
    FOR /R %%z IN (*.rar *.zip *.arj *.lzh *.ace *.7z *.gz *.uue *.bz2 *.jar *.xz *.z) DO (
        SET /A count+=1
        SET /A countpct="(!count!*100)/!countall!"
        <NUL SET /P= %%z ^(!count! / !countall! - !countpct!%%^)
        SET test=!%%z^:^!=!
        ECHO !test!
        WinRAR t !test!
        IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
            ECHO    ERROR^!
            ECHO Errors detected in ^"%%z^" ^| %DATE% %TIME% >>archive_errors.log
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO    OK
        )
    )
) ELSE (
    ECHO Command WinRAR does not exist. Install WinRAR.
    PAUSE
)
ENDLOCAL
EXIT
```

But that doesn't work since ":" is now a trailing character in the variable "test" and the path in the variable seem to have been reduced to a relative path.

Is it possible to keep it simple (is it a syntax error) or do I need another way to remove "!" from the path variable?

Thanks,

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is replace "!" with the escaped exclamation mark ("^!") so that the winrar command still works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorganising...

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* skip=2" %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\WinRAR.exe" /V "Path" 2^>nul') DO SET sti=%%c
IF not EXIST "%sti%\WinRAR.EXE" (
 ECHO Command WinRAR does not exist. Install WinRAR.
 PAUSE
 goto :eof
)
:: WINRAR found
SET PATH="%sti%";!PATH!
SET /a count=0
SET /a countall=0
SET /a countpct=0
IF EXIST archive_errors.log MOVE archive_errors.log archive_errors.log.bck
FOR /R %%b IN (*.rar *.zip *.arj *.lzh *.ace *.7z *.gz *.uue *.bz2 *.jar *.xz *.z) DO SET /A countall+=1 >nul 2>&1
FOR /R %%b IN (*.rar *.zip *.arj *.lzh *.ace *.7z *.gz *.uue *.bz2 *.jar *.xz *.z) DO (
 SET /A count+=1
 SET /A countpct=(count*100^)/countall
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 <NUL SET /P= %%b ^(!count! / !countall! - !countpct!%%^)
 endlocal
 WinRAR t "%%b"
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  ECHO    ERROR!
  ECHO Errors detected in "%%b" ^| %DATE% %TIME% >>archive_errors.log
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO    OK
 )
)
goto :eof
```

Explanation of changes (note: **NOT tested**)

1. Delayedexpansion removed so dealing with `!` as a regular character.
2. Use inverse test for file-presence. If absent, produce error message, pause and exit the program by going to physical end-of-file
3. As `WINRAR` exists, modify `path` using standard variable-extraction.
4. I changed the metavariable `%%z` to `%%b` (I hope throughout) because `z` is one of the metavariable-modifiers. Once bitten, twice shy.
5. a `set /a` can use the syntax shown for calculating `countpct`. `set/a` always works on the runtime-value of variables.
6. Since the display command actually needs to access the run-time value of the elements to show, it needs to be enclosed in a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`/`endlocal` bracket.
7. Can now use `%%b` as filename to test; since `delayedexpansion` is not currently invoked, `!` is just another character.

Note however, that the date and time reported to the `archive_errors` file will be the date and time when the first loop started. If you want the date/time that the error occurred, enclose the error report in `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`/`endlocal` and change to !date! and !time!

Comment: Thanks Magoo! That did it. For some reason I had to put "(count*100)/countall" in quotation marks. Without those the script failed. But works like a charm now :)

Comment: @a15995, it's because the unquoted and unescaped closing `)` closes the parenthesised block of the surrounding `for (…) do ( … )` block…